# Pygame collision trouble

Tags: python, pygame

I've been making progress with this little programme thanks to help received here. Now I get the following error message:  "AttributeError: 'Sprite' object has no attribute 'draw'" which occurs after a collision event, from the line: "orchids.draw(screen)". The programme works fine until the collision event. I'm new to pygame and new to Object Oriented Programming. Any ideas on how to get the programme running?

```
#Import and Init
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

class Orchid(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('orchid1.gif')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = pos
        self.x_inc = 4
        self.y_inc = 4

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.x_inc
        self.rect.y += self.y_inc
        if self.rect.y > 700 or self.rect.y < 0:
            self.y_inc = self.y_inc * -1                   
        if self.rect.x > 1240 or self.rect.x < 0:
            self.x_inc = self.x_inc * -1

#Set Up the Window
width = 1240
height = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pollination!")

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = pygame.image.load("Forrest.jpg")
background = background.convert()

#Load and Convert the wasp
wasp = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
wasp.image = pygame.image.load("wasp1.gif")
wasp.rect = wasp.image.get_rect()
wasp_group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(wasp)

orchids = pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates()

for i in range(7):
    tmp_x = random.randrange(0, 1240)
    tmp_y = random.randrange(0, 700)
    orchids.add(Orchid([tmp_x, tmp_y])) 

buzz = pygame.mixer.Sound("buzz.wav")
#Clock and Loop Variables
framerate = pygame.time.Clock()
GameGo = True

wasp_move = 5
#The Main Loop
while GameGo:

    #Tick the Clock
    framerate.tick(60)

    #Keyborad Keypress Events, Movement

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
        wasp.rect.top -= wasp_move
        if wasp.rect.top < -30:
            wasp.rect.top = -30
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
        wasp.rect.top += wasp_move
        if wasp.rect.top > 625:
            wasp.rect.top = 625
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
        wasp.rect.right -= wasp_move
        if wasp.rect.right < 110:
            wasp.rect.right = 110
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
        wasp.rect.right += wasp_move
        if wasp.rect.right > 1255:
            wasp.rect.right = 1255  

    for orchids in pygame.sprite.groupcollide(wasp_group, orchids, False, True):
        buzz.play()
##  #Blit our Images
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    wasp_group.draw(screen)
    orchids.draw(screen)
    orchids.update()
    pygame.display.update()

  #Handle a Close Event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            GameGo = False

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: `draw` is a method of a sprite group not a single sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop

```
    for orchids in pygame.sprite.groupcollide(wasp_group, orchids, False, True):
        buzz.play()
```

causes the name `orchids` to be assigned to each orchid returned from `groupcollide()`, one by one. In Python, `for` loops don't introduce a new scope, so what's happening is that you're overwriting the name `orchids` each iteration of this loop.

Then, at `orchids.draw`, you are trying to find that method in the individual orchid (the `Sprite` object) when, as Malik Brahimi points out, it's a method of sprite groups. Hence `'Sprite' object has no attribute 'draw'`.

You can fix this by changing the loop variable from `orchids` to `orchid`. Then nothing gets overwritten.

Comment: Excellent work Eli Rose, your suggestion worked well. I will have to think a little more on this, but at the moment I'm very pleased. You saved my hours of frustrating hacking.

Comment: Awesome! Did it turn out to work? Press the check button to 'accept' the answer if it did.